# Matrix of matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to build up the matrix of matrices. Say, for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$ I have to define a matrix $p_{ij}$ which will be a matrix $n\times n$. What I can do - it is to build up a matrix $P$ which is $n^2\times n^2$ - but for $n=20$ there is an error about memory.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: this sounds like a question you might be better off asking on stackoverflow.com

Comment: thanks, I've done it, they helped.

Comment: Voted to close.  Link to stackoverflow version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243507/matrix-of-matrices-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a question you might be better off asking on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use cell array

```
b=rand(20,20);  
c=rand(20,20);
a=cell(20);    %Construct cell array
a{1,1}=b;
a{1,2}=c;
...
```